# I am using reactJs, there I have Box element that contains buy button and moreIcon for menu in mobile view. box element disappears after loggingout

Tags: reactjs

```
<Box
    sx={{
        flexGrow: 0,
        display: {xs: 'flex', md: 'none'},
        alignItems: 'center',
    }}
>
    {!loggedInUserDetails.premium ? (
            <Button
                style={{color: 'white', backgroundColor: 'black'}}
                onClick={handlePaymentModalOpen}
            >
                Buy
            </Button>
        ) :
        //Premiun Icon
        <MenuItem sx={{'&:hover': {backgroundColor: 'transparent', cursor: 'default'}}} disableRipple
                  disablePointerEvents>
            <ListItemIcon>
                <WorkspacePremiumIcon/>
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText style={{color: 'black'}}>Premium</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>}
    <IconButton
        size="large"
        aria-label="show more"
        aria-controls={mobileMenuId}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleMobileMenuOpen}
        color="inherit"
    >
        <MoreIcon style={{color: 'black'}}/>
    </IconButton>
</Box>;
```

this box element disappears after logging out only, once logged In it again appears

I tried adding conditions to the box element, if `loggedInUserDetails` not `null` then the same code as above and if `loggedInUserDetails` is `null` then also the same code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.